# Cannot successfully compile the examples of kernel-gallery

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

I want to try the kernel-gallery, but can not successfully compile the examples on a fresh install of an debian10 system. I always the get the following error, when applying the steps in the readme:

> error: failed to build archive: unexpected metadata version: 1
> (Expected: 2)
>
> The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
>
> warning: In file included from
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/server.c:19:
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/bulk_addition.c:168:1:
> warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces] warning: ADDITION_BTREE(blst_p2, POINTonE2, 384x,
> fp2, BLS12_381_Rx.p2) warning:
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/bulk_addition.c:113:57:
> note: expanded from macro 'ADDITION_BTREE' warning: #define
> ADDITION_BTREE(prefix, ptype, bits, field, one) \ warning:
> ^ warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/bulk_addition.c:57:37:
> note: expanded from macro '\ warning: HEAD' warning:     static const
> vec##bits zero = { 0 }; \ warning:
> ^ warning: In file included from
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/server.c:20:
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:254:1:
> warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces] warning: POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL(blst_p1, POINTonE1,
> 384, fp, BLS12_381_Rx.p) warning:
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:170:46:
> note: expanded from macro 'POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL' warning:     static
> const ptype##_affine infinity = { 0 }; \ warning:
> ^ warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:257:1:
> warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces] warning: POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL(blst_p2, POINTonE2,
> 384x, fp2, BLS12_381_Rx.p2) warning:
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:170:46:
> note: expanded from macro 'POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL' warning:     static
> const ptype##_affine infinity = { 0 }; \ warning:
> ^ warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:257:1:
> warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces] warning: POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL(blst_p2, POINTonE2,
> 384x, fp2, BLS12_381_Rx.p2) warning:
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> warning:
> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/multi_scalar.c:170:46:
> note: expanded from macro 'POINTS_MULT_WBITS_IMPL' warning:     static
> const ptype##_affine infinity = { 0 }; \ warning:
> ^ warning: 4 warnings generated.
>
> error: could not compile `blst` due to previous error warning: build
> failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

The Rust version I am using:

> user@tezos-soru:~/kernel-gallery/00_debug_kernel$ rustc --version
> rustc 1.66.0 (69f9c33d7 2022-12-12)
> user@tezos-soru:~/kernel-gallery/00_debug_kernel$ rustup toolchain
> list
> 1.66.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default) (override) user@tezos-soru:~/kernel-gallery/00_debug_kernel$

The clang version and output of `clang -print-targets`:

> user@tezos-soru:~/kernel-gallery/00_debug_kernel$ clang --version
> clang version 7.0.1-8+deb10u2 (tags/RELEASE_701/final) Target:
> x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /usr/bin

This version does not support "-print-targets". I also could not find a similar flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc is usually the default  c-compiler on a lot of linux systems - you need to ensure that clang is used instead, either though `export CC=clang` or passing it directly when calling cargo: `CC=clang cargo build ...`

Clang needs to be at least v11 (minimum version we have tested with) to be able to pick up the `wasm32` target